# Rails /sitemap.xml redirects to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap

I'm using dynamic_sitemaps gem for generatig sitemap.
https://github.com/lassebunk/dynamic_sitemaps

Locally, when I try to go localhost/sitemap.xml it displays the sitemap file.

When I try this in production on a vps it doesn't work and just redirects me to root_path.

If I cd to public/sitemaps/ I can see the sitemap.xml(it exists).

**What can be wrong here?**

here's my **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  .....

  get 'sitemap' => 'home#sitemap', format: :xml
  get 'robots' => 'home#robots', format: :text#, defaults: { format: :text }
  get '*path', to: 'application#handle_404'
end
```

I've tried to remove `format: :xml` but it didn't work

/robots.txt works fine.

here's my sitemap meth from home controller

```
  def sitemap
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render file: 'public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml' }
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    end
  end
```

handle_404 in application controller

```
  def handle_404
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Comment: your file in public folder is accessible without routes

Comment: I have this folder structure public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml so I need it to work through routes.

Comment: @Gearnode Oh, I think I could also make symlink of public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml to just public/sitemap.xml. In this case you're right. Haven't seen this info in the gem documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem's solved after adding **/** to the beginning of `public/sitemaps...`

```
render file: '/public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml
```